# PHP client IP is invalid

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I running latest PHP with Nginx. I'm trying to get the client's IP address.

Since my web server is behind CloudFlare, I'm using this code to get client's IP address.

It works for almost all the clients.

However, for some USERS IP is different for different providers. It is not the same.

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]
```

For example,

```
On My website => 103.241.21.61
On https://www.whatismyip.com/  => 103.241.21.26
On https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/ => 103.241.21.116
On https://www.iplocation.net/ => 103.241.21.78
On https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip => 103.241.21.101
On https://www.whatismyip-address.com/?check => 103.241.21.51
```

Note that `103.241.21` is static. Last subnet is dynamic for different websites.

All these above providers are showing wrong IP address.

So I did google search "What is my IP" and Google actually showed the correct IP address.

Now how do I know that Google is showing the real IP ?

It is because if I block that IP on Firewall ( Amazon EC2 Security Group ), they can't access the website. So I know this is the real IP.

If I try to block other IPs it doesn't work as those IPs are not the real ones.

Is there any way to know how Google is finding their IP ?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably that cloudflare is unable to detect the proper IP.

Comment: Even if I don't use cloudflare, it still happens. I'll post a video soon.

Comment: I would use REMOTE_ADDR variable... when not using cloudflare